# Submitting parallel unix jobs with hierarchy

Tags: bash, unix

I need to run 3 jobs with the following conditions -

1. `job2` depends on `job1`.
2. `job3` can run independently of `job1` or `job2`.
3. `job4` should start only when `job2` and `job3` both are complete.

I can run `(job1; job2)` to ensure job2 runs after job1. What's the best way to start all the jobs at once to make maximum use of parallelization?

Comment: Let's say it doesn't matter. This solution `(job1; job2; job4) & job3 &` won't work because `job4` can start here before `job3` is complete - rule 3 is not ensured.

Comment: Oops sorry, read that one wrong...

Comment: Np :) To be clear on the question - does it matter if jobs complete successfully - I do not know how to solve it either way. To be specific, let's say it doesn't matter.

Comment: You could do it with a script, but it would be maybe a few lines. You would use background processing and the `wait` to handle `job4`. Actually, something like this may work because of how `wait` works: `(job1; job2) & job3 & wait ; job4`. The `wait` will wait until all child processes complete. In `bash` anyway...

Comment: So `(job1; job2) & x1=$! ; job3 & x2=$! ; (wait $x1 $x2; job4)`?

Comment: Ok cool! Why don't you put that as an answer? I can vote up and accept it. And also curious... why don't many people put their answers as answers - even when it counts - don't you want the rep from votes?

Comment: Just FYI... I sometimes don't put things as an answer if a) I am not 100% certain and I don't have time or inclination to check, or b) I feel it is too trivial to get any points for, or c) I feel there is another answer that is better but mine still has some merit.

Comment: According to the documentation, `wait` without arguments waits for all child processes to complete. So the command line as I showed it *I think* would work as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
job1 &    # Start job1 ASAP as independent
pid1=$!
job3 &    # Start job3 ASAP as independent
pid3=$!
wait $pid1
job2 &
wait $pid2 $pid3
job4
```